# How to ban system soft keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard

I code to ban system soft keyboard.It can achieve the effct,but it disappear after one flash.I don't want this one flash.This is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private EditText mEditText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.test_et);
    mEditText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
                 hideSoftInputMode((EditText)v);
        }
    });

}

private void hideSoftInputMode(EditText editText) {
    ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
            .hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(),
                    InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way - don't lay focus on your EditText. Set it on the View at the background (the Layout) or something. This can be done by using:

```
setFocusable(true);
requestFocus();
```

This should do the trick for you without working with the Manifest etc.

Answer (score 3):

In your manifest file, you can set the `windowSoftInputMode` to `stateAlwaysHidden`:

```
<activity
    ...other attributes
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
</activity>
```